# C# - PHP character encoding mismatch

Tags: c#, php, json, post, character-encoding

We are working on a application wich heavely relies on a stable communication and data transfer between C# and PHP.

---

**The Plan:**

Creating an desktop application in C# in which we can edit values that get returned by making an api request to the PHP server.

---

**The Problem**

When sending values that contain special characters for example: `é` to the PHP by using the C# `RestClient` class we found out that upon reaching the PHP api the value got changed from for example: `é` to `Ã©`.

Upon searching some information about this we have found out that this has to do with the character encoding, the PHP api uses `utf-8` and the C# uses `utf-8` for as far as we know.

---

**The Code**

---

The C# part that sends and creates the request is:

```
string tmp = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deelname);
client = new RestClient((local) ? "http://rotserver" : "https://registrations.roundtexel.com/");
var request = new RestRequest((local) ? "?action=deelname" : "api/bewerk", Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("username", (local) ? Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(User)) : User);
request.AddParameter("type", (local) ? Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("deelname")) : "deelname");
request.AddParameter("inschrijf_id", (local) ? Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inschrijf_id)) : inschrijf_id);
request.AddParameter("stuurman_id", (local) ? Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stuurman_id)) : stuurman_id);
request.AddParameter("bemanning_id", (local) ? Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(bemanning_id)) : bemanning_id);
request.AddParameter("voertuig_id", (local) ? Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(voertuig_id)) : voertuig_id);
request.AddParameter("boot_id", (local) ? Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(boot_id)) : boot_id);
request.AddParameter("content", (local) ? Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tmp)) : tmp);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

---

The PHP/api part of the code:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxxxxx', 'xxxxxx', 'xxxxxx');
    $this->db->exec("SET names utf8;");
}

public function execute(){
    $content = json_decode($_POST['content']);
    #Stuurman
    $stuurman_id = $_POST['stuurman_id'];
    $stuurman = $content->deelnemerStuurman;
    $stmnt = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE `~deelnemer` SET voornaam=?, tussenvoegsel=?, achternaam=?, adres=?, huisnummer=?, toevoeging=?, postcode=?, woonplaats=?, provincie=?, geslacht=?, geboortedatum=?, nationaliteit=(SELECT id FROM `~nationaliteiten` WHERE nationaliteit=?), licentie=1, licentie_nummer=?, telefoonnummer=?, mobielenummer=?, noodnummer=?, email=?, afbeeldingsnaam=?, whatsapp_registratie=? WHERE id=?");
    $stmnt->execute(Array($stuurman->voornaam, $stuurman->tussenvoegsel, $stuurman->achternaam, $stuurman->adres, $stuurman->huisnummer, $stuurman->toevoeging,$stuurman->postcode,$stuurman->woonplaats, $stuurman->provincie, $stuurman->geslacht, $stuurman->geboortedatum,$stuurman->land, $stuurman->licentie_nummer, $stuurman->telefoonnummer, $stuurman->mobielenummer, $stuurman->noodnummer, $stuurman->email, $stuurman->afbeeldingsnaam, $stuurman->whatsapp_registratie, $stuurman_id));
    var_dump($stuurman->voornaam);
    $tmp = "{status: 'success'}";
    return $tmp;
}
```

---

Because of the `var_dump` we have found out that the name: `André` has changed to: `AndrÃ©`

I hope that anybody can help us with this,
Kind Regards,
Jeffrey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to html escape the string so that é is changed to &#233; or &eacute; before you send it.

Use HttpUtility.HtmlEncode in c# and html_entity_decode in php

Comment: since you encode the string to a url encoding you should use urldecode($string) in php